# Struts2 interceptor change action

Tags: struts2

I have added Struts2 interceptor, There I want to change calling action if some logic trigger. Currently I can change redirect JSP file after invoke the action. But I need to change the calling action before invoke the the action. Is there any way to invoke different action?

Thank You.

Comment: You can return whatever result you want, including a global result that maps to an action. Changing the action invocation itself, not so sure--nor am I convinced it's necessary.

Comment: As per my understanding you are trying decide which action to be called in your custom interceptor If so you can't do that. What's your actual requirement.

Comment: your question is not clear enough, but still you can return a result string from your interceptor as suggested by Dave and can use that result string to control the flow of application

Comment: There is common action class like UserAction, for Specific users new Custom Action classes will be introduced. Within the interceptor check the session information, user is specific one then redirect to the new action, instead of invoke action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intercept method as per your comments would look something like this:

```
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation) throws Exception {

        final ActionContext actionContext = ActionContext.getContext();
        final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) actionContext.get(HTTP_REQUEST);
        HttpSession httpSession = httpServletRequest.getSession(false);

        UserObject userObject = session.getAttribute("User"); //Check for user information, this is just a dummy 
        if(isSpecificUser(userObject)){    
            return "SpecificAction";
        }
        return actionInvocation.invoke();
    }
```

`SpecificAction` should be present in your configuration file.

Comment: For annotation based action we have to define 'SpecificAction' in result section of UserAction. Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: Either you define it your actionClass or you define in your struts.xml, for it to be called, without defining action how can you call it ?